# Sensor Diagnostic Tool for Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, sensors

I would like to check my laptop's sensor (e.g. simple device orientation sensor, gyrometer, hinge, etc). I came across the [sensor diagnostic tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/sensors/the-sensor-diagnostic-tool) for Windows 10 but I don't know if it has any equivalents for Ubuntu and I couldn't seem to find any.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick google search, the `lm-sensors` package should fit your purpose. (Note I'll be summarizing [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto)).

Open a terminal window.

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Let the process finish, then

```
sensors-detect
```

And answer **yes** to the corresponding yes or no questions. After this is finished you have a choice to either insert the sensors into /etc/modules automatically (yes) or to manually do it later (no.)

Next, load the necessary modules with

```
sudo service kmod start
```

You will need a monitoring program, further down the article's page there are a few listed, `psensor` being the first listed. Install (your choice)...

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

And launch the executable (or run the application from the terminal window). You should now be able to monitor your sensors.

**For the tablet sensor ([From another AU post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799727/ubuntu-with-tablet-mode-for-lenovo-yoga)):**

```
sudo apt install iio-sensor-proxy inotify-tools
```

NB: You might have to put your computer to sleep and wake it up for the sensor to work. After that, it keeps working.

*Also see [this github repo](https://github.com/alesguzik/linux_detect_tablet_mode)*

Comment: i tried lm-sensors but I couldn't seem to find the specific sensor i was looking for (i was trying to check for the tablet mode sensor). i tried checking psensor as well but it only seems to show me details for the temperature sensor and not other sensors (like gyrometer, as i mentioned). do i need to install any add-ons to see this?

Comment: @xjm Updated post, see bottom

Comment: it seems that it is a bit lacking as compared to the sensor diagnostic tool, but this has most of the functionalities that i was looking for. thanks!